# JedisCluster returns empty cluster nodes

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I am using Jedis using the clustering feature, I am creting cluster nodes and adding them to JedisCluster. However, when JedisCluster is created, empty cluster nodes are returned.
Below is my code written in Java

```
        Set<HostAndPort> jedisClusterNodes = new HashSet<HostAndPort>();
        //Jedis Cluster will attempt to discover cluster nodes automatically
        jedisClusterNodes.add(new HostAndPort("172.17.2.1", 6379));
        jedisClusterNodes.add(new HostAndPort("172.17.1.2", 6379));
        JedisCluster jc = new JedisCluster(jedisClusterNodes);
        Map<String, JedisPool> clusterNodes = jc.getClusterNodes();
```